# What are the differences between RedrawWindow and UpdateWindow in Win32?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, window

What are the differences between RedrawWindow and UpdateWindow in Win32?

Since they seem to have the same purpose to refresh a window, what are the differences?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`RedrawWindow` is typically used to force a redraw of the entire window (or some specified region within) right now.

`UpdateWindow` will force a redraw of only the update region of the window, i.e. that part of the window that has been invalidated (e.g. by calling `InvalidateRect`) since the last paint cycle.

Comment: So, what's the difference between a single call to `RedrawWindow`, and a call to `InvalidateRect` followed immediately by a call to `UpdateWindow`?

Comment: @Cody `RedrawWindow` can also force a repaint of the non-client area of a window (`RDW_FRAME`). `UpdateWindow` only updates the intersection between the update rectangle and the client area.

Comment: It seems that `RedrawWindow` can both 'force immediate redraw' _or_ just 'invalidate', by optional arguments. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2328013/10027592) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13591134/10027592) answers.